# Error in Reference in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, database, wcf, windows-phone

Im trying to connect my Windows Phone app to a WCF. I have a connection but when im trying to use a method in the WCF i get a error in the app Reference.

The line:
    base.EndInvoke("setString", _args, result);

Error message:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Comment: Is there any other information in the error? Inner exception? If you run the app via the simulator, can you capture the network call which was sent (using something like Fiddler)?

Comment: There is no other problem, i have internet and the applikation starts, but when i trying to write something to the method i have there, it responds with this error